# Duplicate keys in the Firebase database

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Actually, I am implementing a Firebase database to store users for my android base.

Basically, this is my User bean :

```
public class User {

    private String idAccount;
    private String firstname;
    private String lastname;
    private String pseudo;
    private Address address;
    private List<Qualification> qualification;
    private boolean isWorker;

    // Constructors + getters + setters

}
```

And, once an User is created, I add it in the database with the method :

```
String idUser = user.getIdAccount();
usersRef.child(idUser).setValue(user);
```

So, this is very simple and it works but I have a little problem. If I check the database : [the user added](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0i8Up.png), I can see the idAccount is duplicate.

I know this is totally normal ! But I am looking for a simple way to remove this field `idAccound` in the database without explicitlu precise all the fields when I use the `setValue(user)`.

Someone has a solution ?

Thank you !!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the `@Exclude` annotation.

https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/database/Exclude

```
public class User {
    @Exclude
    private String idAccount;
    private String firstname;
    private String lastname;
    private String pseudo;
    private Address address;
    private List<Qualification> qualification;
    private boolean isWorker;

    // Constructors + getters + setters

}
```

I would not do this, but that's how.

Comment: Yes this is what i was looking for !

Answer (score 1):

To remove that field from your entire database, please use the following code:

```
DatabaseReference rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
DatabaseReference usersRef = rootRef.child("users");
ValueEventListener eventListener = new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        for(DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
            ds.child("idAccount").getRef().removeValue();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {}
};
usersRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(eventListener);
```

After that, just simply add `@Exclude` annotation in front of the field in your model class like this:

```
@Exclude
private String idAccount;
```

If you are still in testing with your app, you can also remove the `private String idAccount;` entirely.